# Solving a radially symmetric Dirichlet problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dirichlet-series

How do I solve this Dirichlet problem?

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 1 & \quad  \mbox{ on $ x^2 + y^2< a^2\ $,} \\
\quad u(x,y) = 0 & \quad  \mbox{ on $ x^2 + y^2 = a^2\ $}.
\end{array} 
\right. $$

would the solution be $u(r) = \frac{r^2-1}{4}$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Symmetry suggests that $u(\rho,\phi)=f(\rho)$ is independent of $\phi$.  Hence, we have

$$\nabla^2 u(\rho,\phi)=\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho}\left(\rho \frac{\partial f(\rho)}{\partial \rho}\right)=1$$

with $f(a)=0$.

Can you finish now?